# Packaging Spring Jars in the exported Spring project - better way?

Tags: java, spring, jar, manifest, wildcard

I'm exporting a spring project as JAR. Now the problem is, I need to take care of spring jar files dependencies.

One option for this is, include all the JAR files in the `Class-Path` header of the *MANIFEST.MF* file (A Real Pain in the neck). Second option I tried is using the Command Line, but of course, we can't have both `-cp` and `-jar` options to work together. Once we have `-jar`, `-cp` will get ignored.

To ease out the first option, I wondered if I could introduce some wildcard here. So, I gave it a try, and changed my MANIFEST as:

```
Class-Path: lib/*
```

Nothing happened. This confirmed that Manifest headers don't treat `*` as wildcard -> **FAILED**.

Then I moved onto the second option. I did a little tweaking there. I got rid of the JAR file, and decided to work with simple directory structure containing my class files. Then I created a *batch* file, with the command to run the main class, passing all the JAR files using wildcards as command line argument:

```
java -cp .;./* MainClass
```

and then I simply ran the batch file. Thankfully it worked. But I don't want it this way.

If only there was some way to get it done using JAR file only, that would be much better option. Do I have any option here? The only thing that I doubt is am I using the Wildcards the right way in the MANIFEST header? Do the MANIFEST headers consider wildcards at all?

---

**NOTE**: I can't use Maven. So, it's not an option here.

Comment: If you are using Maven, you could create an überjar containing all of the dependencies as well as your application code in a single jar.  If this is of interest, I can provide you a fuller answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven and the "maven-assembly-plugin". Then you only have to type "mvn assembly:assembly" and it creates a big .jar file that includes not only your classes but also all the dependend jars. You can then simply run the app with "java -jar target/myproject-1.0-with-dependencies.jar.

You have to create a src/main/resources/assembly.xml though, take the example here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it earlier that I can't use Maven. I'm behind the Organization Proxy.

Comment: If you mean Proxy like in Firewall, you can either configure the same HTTP Proxy you use in your browser in /etc/maven/settings.xml or download packages by hand and install them somehow with "mvn" (I assume that you have to download the dependend jars somehow manually anayway).
At least you could try out the assembly plugin how it calls jar to build a .jar with other dependency jars in it.